# Swift 3 names (uppercase or not)?

Tags: swift, syntax

I am new in Swift.
Where can I find an overview for the right names in Swift 3?

- Classnames = classNameOne
- String: myString
- Function: myFunction(myTest : string, myNumber : Int)
- Struct: myStructOne
- Label: lblOne
- Button: btnTwo or cmd?
- Image: imgThree

I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: Have you try google?

Comment: Dont know what to search for?

Comment: Enjoy: https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide

Comment: Ahhh styleguide thanks

Comment: Swift team's guidelines: https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ Can you elevate this to an answer? Swift's document design guidelines are the authoritative answer. While other positions are opinions, it's hard to argue against things from swift.org about how to write Swift. Those guidelines directly touch on the question given the "uppercase or not" portion (and also they give extensive explanation of how to name other things, though not buttons in particular)

Comment: Also note that there are extensive Cocoa-specific naming guidelines provided by Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html In particular, names like `lblOne` would violate the convention "In general, don’t abbreviate names of things." (That would be expected to be named `firstLabel` in any case. Cocoa does not use Hungarian notations.)

Comment: @RobNapier Added. The Swift guidelines have a similar section as well.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. Now i have many to read ... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the most part naming conventions are relatively subject to opinion, but the syntax of your naming conventions should be universal. [Ray Wenderlich](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide) has a great style guide for Swift that I believe all Swift developers should follow. It adhears to the "Camel-Case" of first letter in the class name is capitalize as well as each successive word (`class MyClass`) and keeping the first character of each variable name as lowercase, then each successive word is capitalized (`var myVariable`).

Answer (score 3):

Of course there is no rule for this (But there are Guidelines). But the common accepted way is like this (I put in bold the ones that change from what you wrote):

- Classnames = **C**lassNameOne
- String: myString
- Function: myFunction(myTest : string, myNumber : Int)
- Struct: **M**yStructOne
- Label: lblOne
- Button: btnTwo
- Image: imgThree

Comment: I'm not sure why you say there's no rule for this. Swift's API Design Guidelines would seem an authoritative rule, and covers this question well: https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/

Comment: What I mean, is that if you want you can do it as you please, Of course there are guidlines, Will edit my question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

As with any language, there's no one way everyone does things.

The only "official" source is [Swift's official guidelines](http://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines). Beyond that it depends on you and/or your company's preferences.